# how to create AFNetworking 3 from-data request

Tags: objective-c

[image]

MY CODE IS FOR AFNETWOKING 3.0

```
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"multipart/form-data"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:30];

[manager POST:URLString parameters:param progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    if([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        RequestCompletionHandlerBlock(responseObject);

    }
    else {
        NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
        RequestCompletionHandlerBlock(response);

    }
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"Error Is %@",error.description);

    RequestFailedHandlerBlock(@{@"error " :error.description});

}];
```

RESPONCE IS : 
NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html

Comment: my param is value:>>
  NSDictionary *param = @{@"api_key":@"123123",
                            @"username":self.txt_Use_name.text,
                            @"fullname":self.txt_Full_Name.text,
                            @"gender":self.txt_Gender.text,
                            @"email":self.txt_Email.text,
                            @"password":self.txt_Password.text,
                            @"password_confirmation":self.txt_Rtype_Password.text};

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
        manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

        [manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:30];

        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

        [manager POST: URLString parameters:param constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {

        } progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

        } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
 NSLog(@"all data=%@",responseObject);
}
                    }
              failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

                           }];
```

Comment: @Milan Vadgama you got your solution ?